# Blend 'Invalid Markup' after csproj change for win8 apps

Tags: windows-8, blend

I'm working on several UI-heavy Win8 apps. 
Blend usually updates fine after changing files in VS2012 (have to rebuild to make viewModels show up as design data though)

The problem I have is that every time I make a change to the project in VS2012, eg add a file, and the .csproj file gets updated, Blend seems to drop all XAML knowledge and complains about everything with a message: "Invalid Markup".

After restarting Blend everything is back to normal.

Ideas? Thanks!